# Show difference between BMP files

Tags: command-line, image-processing

Is there a command line tool to show the difference between two BMPs in such a way that it would return the difference in their header values in a human readable way?  So, there would be information like difference in width, height, image size, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick  
identify 'path/to/image1.bmp'  
identify 'path/to/image2.bmp'
```

Sample output:

```
/home/noah/Pictures/image1.bmp BMP 2515x2520 2515x2520+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 6.341MB 0.050u 0:00.019
```

Comment: thanks didnt know about identify, has slightly better info than file

Answer (score 4):

You can use `file` command to get information about multiple file.

`file  2.1.bmp 2.2.bmp 2.3.bmp`

`2.1.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 640 x 300 x 24
2.2.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 640 x 300 x 24
2.3.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 640 x 300 x 24`

(since my all three file are of same size but you can find difference in width, hight,depth  of your file.)